# What is the name of words or phrases people insert into sentences, seemingly unintentionally? And the practice?

Tags: terminology

For instance, I have a friend who just can't help himself constantly saying "ok". He'll say things like "ok, now we're going to [...]" or "now we've seen that, ok", and I'm just wondering what this practice is called.

I used to think this sort of thing was called a "verbal tic", but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic#Motor_or_phonic):

> Phonic tics are involuntary sounds produced by moving air through the nose, mouth, or throat. They may be alternately referred to as **verbal tics** or **vocal tics**, but most diagnosticians prefer the term phonic tics to reflect the notion that the vocal cords are not involved in all tics that produce sound.

Comment: A personal 'interjection'.

Comment: Wikipedia gives the formal medical definition, but [verbal tic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tic?q=verbal+tic#tic__6) does work colloquially.

Comment: It's a 'pragmatic marker'. If it's largely automatic or to give him a moment to formulate the next sentence, it's a 'filler' and is speaker-orientated. In other circumstances, when it's used to grab attention ('Right!/OK! We're now going to ...') it's audience-orientated and a focusing particle (perhaps to gain the audience's initial  attention, perhaps signalling a transition in dialogue).

Comment: That quote from wikipedia doesn't actually say that **verbal tic** has the same *definition* as **phonic tic**. It just says that the former can also be used for the latter and that the latter is preferred precisely because the former (along with **vocal tic**) is likely to be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Crutch words* comes to mind. Although I have difficulty finding any official definition, I have heard it /read it very often ( mostly used by speech trainers ).

Here's an example of a text where the expression is used (not to be seen as an official reference, of course):

*[20 most annoying words and phrases that should basically be banned at the end of the day](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/20-most-annoying-words-phrases-16541161)*

> Teachers at Copthorne Primary in Bradford are, like, helping youngsters to improve their, um, fluency by outlawing, you know, filler words.
>
> Which is, like, music to the ears of millions irked by the, ah, growing use of verbal tics and pointless phrases.
>
> They’re known as “**crutch words**” because we rely on them too much – and here are the 20 worst..

Answer (score 2):

In linguistics, these words are often referred to as **filler words**.

This includes both **vocal pauses** (sounds like "er" and "um")and **discourse markers** such as "you know?" and "so" and "like".

Answer (score 0):

The general term 'vocalized pause' is used to describe several words, like 'ok', 'well. 'mmm', etc. which are sub-grouped under headings: turn-taking cues, turn-yielding cues, turn-maintaining cues, etc. The vocalized pause is a subject of extensive study by a chap named Duncan.