# What do you call it when people say 'like' a lot?

Tags: linguistics, sociolinguistics

So like, I like, have like, a like, question, like, you know!

Like, is there a, like, term, for, like, when someone, like, talks, like, like this, you know?

PS: I'm also curious to know what other words and phrases are often used in conjunction with this style of speaking, e.g. "you know".

Comment: I am asking what this style of talking is called, just like the title states.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name of the words or phrases people insert into sentences, seemingly unintentionally? And the practice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186993/what-is-the-name-of-the-word-or-phrase-people-insert-into-sentences-seemingly-u)

Comment: [linguistically-challenged conversation?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22linguistically-challenged+conversation%22)

Comment: I call it 'annoying'.

Comment: It's "Valley Speak".